# Why does this VBA code give me an Object Required error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in an Excel macro:

```
Dim cellRange As range
Dim cell As range
Dim cellFormula As String
Dim yearCells As New Collection

For Each cellRange In ranges
    For Each cell In cellRange.Cells
        cellFormula = GetCellFormula(cell)
        If (cellFormula = formulaYears) Then
            yearCells.Add (cell)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Where `ranges` is a `Collection` object holding many Range objects.

When I run the code, I get an "Object required" error on the line `For Each cellRange In ranges`. Why is this? After all, `cellRange` is declared as an object, i.e. `Dim cellRange As range`. If I convert the code to a `For` loop, I have the same error on a line:

```
Set cellRange = ranges(i)
```

BTW, my VBA IDE insists on `range` always having a lower case initial letter. When I type `Range` the editor "corrects" it to `range`. Yet other code using `range` objects works fine.

Comment: Can we see how you populate the collection too?

Comment: _my VBA IDE insists on range_ you have probably a global variable/sub/function named `range` somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lays in the way you populate your collection I'm sure. For example see the following:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ranges As New Collection
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
Dim cellRange As Range, cell As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A1:A3")
Set rng2 = Range("B1:B3")
Set rng3 = Range("C1:C3")

ranges.Add rng1
ranges.Add rng2
ranges.Add rng3

For Each cellRange In ranges
    Debug.Print cellRange.Address
    For Each cell In cellRange
        Debug.Print cell.Address
    Next cell
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I was using `rangeCollection.Add(theRange)`, with parenthesis, which apparently forces the argumant to by passed `ByVal`. I removed the parenthesis and now my loop is working!